# Updating notificationMenuOutput - strange redirect to other tab

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, shinydashboard

I have a ShinyDashboard Page with a notificationMenu inside the header. I update these notifications from inside a Page in the Dashboard. This works perfectly, but after updating the notification Items, the User is redirected to the first Tab of the App - which is a strange behaviour. I expected to stay at the current page, even after the update was triggered. Does anyone have an explanation?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("notificationMenu")), 
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Page 1", tabName = "page1"),
                                                 menuItem("Page 2", tabName = "page2"))),
                    dashboardBody(tabItems(
                      tabItem(tabName = "page1", h4("This is Page 1")),
                      tabItem(tabName = "page2", 
                              textInput("text", "Enter News:", "New News."),
                              actionButton("save", "Save")))))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  raw_news <- reactiveValues()

  # Intial Header News: 1 Message from Admin
  raw_news$news <- data_frame(from = "Admin", text = "this is a message")

  # The notifications in header
  output$notificationMenu <- renderMenu({
    raw_news <- raw_news$news

    dropdownMenu(
      messageItem(raw_news$from[1], raw_news$text[1])
    )
  })

  # save a new notification
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    raw_news$news <- data.frame(from = "User", text = input$text)
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: issue: https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/229 // workaround: https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in the `shinydashboard` package and has been fixed in Version 0.6.1.9000. It is not on CRAN by today, so the devtools-Version from github should do, or alternatively there is a workaround: Add

`sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar"`

and

`updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", input$sidebar)`

in `output$notificationMenu`

Further information: [Issue and fix on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/pull/233)